# opening text file in 'r' mode and printing the list( <filehandle> ) gives a list of all lines

Tags: python, file-handling

I recently, by mistake, found out that if I print out the list( filehandle ) in python for a file open in 'r' mode, it print out a list of all lines of the file.

File trial.txt:

```
12345
67890
abcd
```

Code:

```
a = open("trial.txt", 'r')
print( list(a) )
```

Output:

```
['12345\n', '67890\n', 'abcd']
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

File implements python interators functions:  `__next__` & `__iter__`

When you make a list of out of file handle, these will be called by list and populate it with the data from the file.